# generate image url with twig function asset

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I imagine that what i am going to ask is possible.

Let's say I have a javascript file defining some jquery default options (for JQGrid for instance)

```
function defineGridsSettings() {
  $.extend($.jgrid.defaults,{
    jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records"
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    viewrecords: true,
    imgpath: '../jquery/css/images'
  });
}
```

My problem concerns the path to the image folder so I would like to use something like :

```
{{ asset('bundles/.....') }} for the imgpath
```

my file name is jqueryObjectSettings.js.twig

I use Assetic to load it...of course the twig functions are not translated.

Can I ask to translate the twig instructions in js files like that ?

Thank you

Comment: Do you install your assets on the web? If yes, you may know the exact path of your assets like `bundles/mybundle/jquery/css/images/xyz.png`? Now is your problem with `../` in your imgpath?

Comment: You are right, I know, but I was wondering if there was an easy way to do it like in a twig-way. Can I ask to "compile" those xxx.js.twig ?

Comment: Therfore you have two options: A) change your js file to be a twig file like `xxx.js.twig` and render the view. In this case you can just set `imgPath: "../{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/jquery/css/images') }}"`. B) define a public javascript var in your twig template page (not the javascript file) and set the asset path as `var mypath = "{{ asset('bundles/mybundle/jquery/css/images') }}"` now in your js file you can set imgpath as `imgpath: '../' + mypath`